# Vector giving inaccurate output

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<int> vect;
vector<int> sorted;

vect.push_back(5);
vect.push_back(3);
vect.push_back(7);
vect.push_back(2);
vect.push_back(9);
vect.push_back(6);

//Print vector elements
for (int x=0; x<vect.size(); x++)
    cout <<  vect[x] << endl;

int min = 99999, idx=0;    
while (vect.size() > 0)
{
    for (int x=0; x<vect.size(); x++)
    {
        if (vect[x] < min)
        {
            min = vect[x];
            idx = x;
        }
    }
    cout << "Min index: " << idx << endl;
    sorted.push_back(vect[idx]);
    vect.erase(vect.begin()+idx);        
}   
for (int x=0; x<sorted.size(); x++)
    cout <<  sorted[x] << endl;
```

I wanted to sort the vector of integers by storing the sorted numbers into `vector<int> sorted`. But the program always got terminated half way after hitting some unknown program error.

```
The only output I get is:

5
3
7
2
9
6

Min Index: 3
Min Index: 3
Min Index: 3
Min Index: 3
<Program Terminated At This Point>
```

I've been working on this for hours and I don't know why I always get index 3 as the smallest number. What have I done incorrectly in my implementation? 
I have been thinking on it for hours, and my logic seems correct?

Comment: If you actually want to sort this way I think you'll need to reset `min` each time before the inner `for` loop. Or you could just use `std::sort` from the C++ standard library...

Comment: omg..  I can't believe I made such silly mistakes. I've been coding for past 20 hours without sleep... I am really sorry for this mistake. I shouldn't be asking this in here.

Comment: Yes, sleep is important. Knowing when you are no longer effective is super important. You can do a LOT of damage if you are not optimal. Find employers that understand this, or you will waste a lot of your life.

Comment: @LeeLouviere Thanks for your comment. Btw, is there a better way to sort vectors? I feel that my way is abit inefficient..

Comment: Saw Blastfurnace's reply. `sort (vect.begin(), vect.end());` works perfectly. Thanks all.

Comment: setting `min` to `INT_MAX` rather than `99999` will also avoid screwy behaviour in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

On your first pass, it finds out min is 2.
It then erases 2, which is at index 3.
Then it goes through again, except nothing is smaller than 2.
So it still has index 3, and erases it.
This continues until you no longer have more than 3 items.
Then it fails, because the vector is too small to erase index 3.

Reset your min back to 99999 before your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As what user Blastfurnace had pointed out. I forgot to reset the Min.
This should solve it.

```
int idx=0;    
while (vect.size() > 0)
{
    int min = 99999;
    for (int x=0; x<vect.size(); x++)
    {
        if (vect[x] < min)
        {
            min = vect[x];
            idx = x;
        }
    }
    cout << "Min index: " << idx << endl;
    sorted.push_back(vect[idx]);
    vect.erase(vect.begin()+idx);        
}
```

Comment: Just know that this is the most inefficient way possible to sort.
You're using erase which has to reshuffle the items every time you do that. So you're looking at O(2^n) here.